# libsymbolic.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gdb, shared-libraries

I am trying to debug my C++ application from the shell.

> gdb --args [scripts' parameters...]

Then, in the gdb:

> (gdb) run

and I get the output:

> error while loading shared libraries: libsymbolic.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> [Inferior 1 (process 15453) exited with code 0177]

If it helps:

> (gdb) show solib-search-path
>
> The search path for loading non-absolute shared library symbol files is .
>
> (gdb) shell ls $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> ls: cannot access /usr/lib/libipp-intel: No such file or directory
>
> (gdb) shell echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> /usr/lib/libipp-intel

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The tcshrc file (located mostly at ~/.tcshrc) may define the value of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

The needed relevant code segment (on my case) in the tcshrc file was:

> if ($?LD_LIBRARY_PATH) then
>
> > setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/libipp-intel:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> else
>
> > setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/libipp-intel:
>
> endif

Hope it will help others.